# createTextNode depending on href destination - No jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML...

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a class="one" href="example.html">
   <span class="two">_____</span></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Of which the textNode between `span` tags is changed depending on the `href` destination of the parent `a` tag, using the following JavaScript:

```
var href = document.querySelector(".one").getAttribute("href");
var two = document.querySelectorAll(".two");

var example = document.createTextNode("example");

if (href.startsWith("example")) {
  two.forEach(function(twoExample) {
    twoExample.appendChild(example);
    })
  }
```

This works, however, I have a number of `a` and `span` tags that share the same `className`, for which I'm trying to apply that same JavaScript; so if another `a` tag had a `href` of **sample**, the textNode will change accordingly for the following desired outcome:

```
var href = document.querySelector(".one").getAttribute("href");
var two = document.querySelectorAll(".two");

var example = document.createTextNode("example");

if (href.startsWith("example")) {
  two.forEach(function(twoExample) {
    twoExample.appendChild(example);
    })
  }

<html>
 <body
  <a class="one" href="example.html">
   <span class="two">example</span></a>
 </body>
</html>

var example = document.createTextNode("sample");

if (href.startsWith("sample")) {
  two.forEach(function(twoSample) {
    twoSample.appendChild(sample);
    })
  }

<html>
 <body>
  <a class="one" href="sample.html">
   <span class="two">sample</span></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't, the first `if` function seems to override the rest of the other functions, aswell as appending the child to the last element with the same `className` disregarding `href` destination.

I'm unsure on a fix to this, hence the question. If anyone has an answer it'd be greatly appreciated!

Note: only Vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do it with simple CSS:

```css
a.one[href^=example]::before {
  content: 'example';
}

a.one[href^=sample]::before {
  content: 'sample';
}
```

```html
<a class="one" href="example.html"></a>
<a class="one" href="sample.html"></a>
```

Of course you can still style `::after` pseudo element same as span in case you need to.

In case you still want to learn your JS code, you need to loop over all links and change inner `span` `textContent` property. For example like this:

```js
var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.one'))

links.forEach(function(link) {
  var span = link.querySelector('.two')
  var href = link.getAttribute('href')

  if (href.startsWith('example')) {
    span.textContent = 'example'
  } else if (href.startsWith('sample')) {
    span.textContent = 'sample'
  }
})
```

```html
<a class="one" href="example.html">
  <span class="two"></span>
</a>
<a class="one" href="sample.html">
  <span class="two"></span>
</a>
```